# What time does "Vormittag" start and end?

Tags: word-usage, time

This morning I read someone's message (written at 7am) saying that he likes *"den frühen Vormittag"*.

In my opinion 7am in the morning isn't *Vormittag* yet. Is there a definition for the time span which is covered by the term? Also, how about *Mittag*, *Nachmittag*, *Abend* and *Nacht*?

Comment: Here on the local radio, they say "Guten Tag liebe Zuhörer, guten Morgen liebe Studenten."

Comment: If the morning is when you have breakfast, and you have lunch around the middle of the day... then surely Vormittag begins around brunch?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I bet this is very subjective and fuzzy but by my definition it would be something like this:

- up to about 10 am is *Morgen*
- until noon (12 o'clock sharp) it's *Vormittag*
- 12 till 1 or maybe 2 pm is *Mittag*
- until 5 or 6 pm it's *Nachmittag*
- after that it's *Abend* until about 10 pm
- after that it's *Nacht*

I think especially the transitions from *Morgen* to *Vormittag* and *Nachmittag* to *Abend* are very subjective because they are caused by each individual's work day. So for a baker that starts working at 4 am this could be *Morgen*; for others this might still be *Nacht* (e.g. for me, I get up at about 7 am).

People who work late (say until 8 pm) might say their *Abend* starts at that time.

Comment: +1, nice explanation, especially for the hint that it depends on the individual work day.

Comment: Well, when does "Nacht" change to "Morgen"? At 0:00?

Comment: @Tim: For me *Morgen* starts at something like 6 or 7 am. 5 o'clock might be *Früher Morgen*. Anything earlier is definitely *Nacht*. Again, YMMV.

Comment: Mostly Nacht is before sleep and morgen is when you wake up. Or if you don't sleep, when the sun rises. This is the molst common usage that I have found.

Comment: Die Darstellung suggeriert dass die Zeiträume sich nicht überlappen sondern nahtlos aneinander anschließen. Verstärkt wird der Eindruck dadurch, dass trotz ausdrücklicher Frage kein **von** angegeben ist. Ich halte das für falsch.

Comment: Das stimmt einigermaßen mit CLDR überein, wobei viele  Daten dort auch nicht intensiv empirisch erhoben wurden, sondern man sich weitgehend auf das Know-how und Feedback der Übersetzer verlässt: https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/43/supplemental/day_periods.html

Answer (score 10):

Die Unterteilung der [Tageszeiten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tageszeit) geht auf die römische Zeitrechnung zurück. Bei [Nikolaus A. Bär](http://www.nabkal.de/index.html) findet sich folgende umfassende Auflistung:

> *ante lucem* (Morgendämmerung)
>   *dilucium* (Tagesanbruch)
>   *mane* (früher Vormittag)
>   *ad meridiem* (später Vormittag)
>   *meridies* (Mittag)
>   *de meridie* (früher Nachmittag)
>   *suprema* (später Nachmittag)
>   *vespera* (erste Dämmerung)
>   *crepusculum* (Abenddämmerung)
>   *luminibus accensis* oder *prima face* (erste Abendzeit)
>   *concubium* (Schlafenszeit, Mitte zwischen Sonnenuntergang und Mitternacht)
>   *nox intempesta*
>   *ad mediam noctem* (Vor-Mitternacht)
>   *media nox* (Mitternacht)
>   *de media nocte* (Nach-Mitternacht)
>   *gallicinum* (Hahnenschrei, Mitte zwischen Mitternacht und Sonnenaufgang)
>   *conticinium* (erstes Morgenlicht)

Schon an der Abhängigkeit vieler dieser Zeitangaben von dem Stand der Sonne wird klar, dass es keine festen Uhrzeitangaben geben kann. Die Zeiten werden subjektiv benannt. Eine "amtliche" Regelung existiert nicht.

Comment: Hübsche Antwort, dafür +1. Sind aber natürlich viel mehr Zeitangaben, als wir sie heute wirklich verwenden :)

Comment: Für "Nacht" gibt es sogar eine amtliche Regelung: genauer für die "[Nachtzeit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachtzeit)". Die Zeitspanne hängt auch noch davon ab, ob Sommer oder Winter ist und ob es um Straf- oder Zivilrecht geht. Also eigentlich ganz einfach und übersichtlich ;)

Answer (score 5):

musiKk already gave a good explanation. I think, however, that the definition might totally depend on your day (since it's really very subjective), especially on your *Essgewohnheiten* (eating habits):

- From waking up until about breakfast time, it's *Morgen* (maybe for another hour)
- Lunch time is *Mittag* (hence *Mittagessen*)
- Evening meal time starts *Abend* (hence *Abendbrot* / *Abendessen*)
- Between breakfast and lunch, it's *Vormittag*
- Between lunch and evening meal, it's *Nachmittag*
- Night starts when you go to bed (or some time before), and ends when you wake up. Since the *Morgen* is the first part of the day, this also means that the new day also starts *after you woke up* - and not right after midnight.
- When you get home from work, it is *Feierabendzeit* - note that there's also *Abend* in the word.

This leads to situations like this: When I come to work, it's *Morgen* for me - but some people greet me with *Mahlzeit* - even though by other definitions, like the one by musiKk, this is *Vormittag* ;) On the other hand, this doesn't matter, since we mostly say *Moin* all day.

The consequence of this definition is that for example some people have *Mittag* at 11 am, while others have it at 2 pm. For some, the *Morgen* ends at 7 am, for others it ends at 10 am. This seems to match usage of these words for many people (from my observations).

All these time expressions can be modified with *früh* or *spät*. *Später Morgen* and *früher Vormittag* blend into each other, *später Vormittag* and *Mittag*, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have already correctly pointed out that daytime periods are quite subjective and may differ by region, season, personal habits and many other factors. In some situations, however, there is a need to objectively and absolutely specify such terms. The [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/29/supplemental/day_periods.html) which is relied upon (at least as a default) by most software manufactures has defined the local start times for the German language, without regional variation:

- 00:00 *Nacht*
- 05:00 *Morgen*
- 10:00 *Vormittag*
- 12:00 *Mittag*
- 13:00 *Nachmittag*
- 18:00 *Abend*

Not all native speakers will agree with these times, but the CLDR is usually well researched and provides a good enough guideline for many purposes. It’s also convenient for a first comparison to other languages and cultures.

Comment: TV programming has similar but different ideas about the [daily schedule](https://filmlexikon.uni-kiel.de/doku.php/s:sendezeitenubersicht-4952): ca. from 05:30/06:00 Morgen/Frühstück, 09:00/10:00 Vormittag, 12:00/13:00 Mittag, 14:00 Nachmittag, 17:00/18:00 Vorabend, 19:00/20:00 Abend, 22:00/23:00 Spät, 00:00/01:00 Nacht (03:00 day change)

Answer (score 2):

Man kann sich m.E. nicht mit der Floskel "subjektiv" begnügen, um unterschiedliche Vorstellungen zu klassifizieren, sondern muss herausarbeiten, auf was die Subjektivität sich stützt, denn in der Sprache sucht man fast immer Verständigung mit anderen, und daraus folgt, dass das, was ich benutze auch verstanden werden muss.

Der leitende Gedanke ist der, dass es eine objektive Zäsur gibt, die für viele Leute Mittagspause oder Mittagessen sind, und was davor ist, ist vormittags, was danach nachmittags. Für den Beginn ergibt sich daraus keine einfache Terminierungsmöglichkeit - vielleicht die, dass der Beginn der Tätigkeit, die mit der Mittagspause unterbrochen wird, den Vormittag i.d.R. markiert - Extremsituationen aber ausgenommen, etwa wenn Bergsteiger um 5:00 Uhr aufbrechen.

Dementsprechend könnte für Berufstätige, die um 9:00 beginnen, da auch der Vormittag beginnen und für Schüler um 8:00 Uhr. Es ist aber, wenn man nicht Schichtarbeit leistet oder Langschläfer aus Passion in Rente, Urlaub, usw. ist möglich die ganze Zeit nach dem Aufstehen als Vormittag zu bezeichnen.

Eine strenge Einordnung nach Uhrzeit gibt es nicht, und die verschiedenen Phasen müssen auch nicht streng aneinander anschließen, sondern können sich überlappen. Man könnte also in der Schule sagen, dass man so früh am morgen, etwa um 9:15 Uhr, noch nicht ganz fit ist. Gleichwohl könnte man zur selben Zeit sagen, dass man vormittags noch nicht trinkt.

Sonst würde ich den Vormittag streng genommen von 6 Uhr früh bis 12 Uhr exclusiv (wg. 'Vor'mittag.) gehen lassen. Mittag ist um 12, und davor ist vormittag. Aber vor 6 Uhr früh ist es noch Nacht, und zwar wenn man sonst nichts über lokale Konventionen weiss. Heißt es "Das Museum ist vormittags geschlossen" würde ich annehmen bis Punkt 12.

Und Nachmittag ist nach 12 aber bis 6. Mittag hier als Zeitpunkt gedacht, nicht als ~spanne. Aber der Mittag als Zeitspanne geht wohl von 11:00 bis 14:00 Uhr. *Mittag* wird aber oft auch als Nachmittag verstanden.

Der Abend überlappt sich mit späten Nachmittag. Um 17:30 Uhr ist es schon früher abend.

Je nach Kontext kann sich aus diesem auch eine andere Zeitspanne ergeben: Mittagsruhe (13:00-15:00 Uhr), Mittagspause, Abendvorstellung im Kino. Auch würde ich im dt. Winter eher früher von 'abends' sprechen, als im Sommer. Solange es noch hell ist von 'nachts' zu sprechen widerstrebt mir, aber kl. Kinder um 20:30 Uhr ins Bett schicken im Winter, weil es schon Nacht ist, wäre genau meine Rede. Im Sommer dagegen: weil es schon spät ist.

Comment: Vor 6 Uhr früh ist es noch Nacht, auch wenn es schon hell ist, ja? `:-)` Ich würde um 6:10 Uhr übrigens _niemals_ von "Vormittag" sprechen, stimme also den anderen zu, dass das ganze sehr subjektiv ist.

Comment: Ich bin oft um 10 vor 6 noch wach, und würde bejahen - es ist dann noch Nacht. Das Nachtprogramm des ÖR geht allerdings nur bis 5:30, dann kommt das Morgenmagazin. Um 5:50 ist jedenfalls noch nicht vormittag, aber `morgens früh` als überlappenden Bereich über noch nachts, und schon vormittags.

Comment: Der "noch Nacht" Teil meines Kommentars bezog sich darauf, dass es Dir widerstrebt, von 'nachts' zu sprechen, solange es _noch_ hell ist. Bei _schon_ scheint es also anders zu sein `:-)`

Comment: Genau! Ich diskriminiere den Morgen. Auf dem Land nimmt man vielleicht auch noch Geflügel zur Hilfe, und in religiösen Tälern das Gebimmel von Kirchenglocken. Wenn mein Nachbar um 5:30 Uhr die Bohrmaschine in die Wand steckt, dann verklage ich ihn wg. Störens der Nachtruhe, nicht? :) Und das auch im Sommer.

Answer (score 2):

In der guten alten Zeit, als "normale Menschen" noch von 7:30 Uhr bis 17:00 Uhr gearbeitet haben (also bis vor etwa 20 Jahren), war das einfach:

"Morgen" ist von 7:30 Uhr bis zur Frühstückspause (die von 9:00 - 9:15 geht)

"Vormittag" ist von 9:15 Uhr bis zur Mittagspause (die von 12:15-13:00 geht und den "Mittag" darstellt)

"Nachmittag" von 13:00 Uhr bis zum "Feierabend" - Also 16:30 oder 17:00. Alles was danach (bzw. nach dem Abendessen um 17:30 oder 18:00 Uhr) ist, ist "Abend", die "Nacht" startete um 22:00 Uhr, wo Leute, die "wussten, was sich gehört" ins Bett gingen.

(Die Zeitangaben können um 1/2 bis ganze Stunde abweichen)

Allerdings sieht man daran, dass sich die Zeiteinteilung an den Mahlzeiten, die schon immer eine feste Zäsur im Tagesablauf waren, festmacht. Die moderne Arbeitswelt mit flexibleren und individuellen Zeiten hat hier manches durcheinandergewürfelt und die Tageszeiten eher dem jeweils eigenen Tageszyklus und Zeitgefühl angepasst. Ausser, dass das Mittagessen in unseren Breiten typischerweise irgendwann zwischen 12:00 und 13:00 stattfindet, haben sich alle anderen dieser Zäsuren individuell verschoben. In vielen Betrieben findet das Phänomen der Früstückspause gar nicht mehr statt. Was "Morgen", "Vormittag" "Nachmittag" und "Abend" ist, legt jeder für sich selbst in gewissen Grenzen fest, diese Grenzen können von den obigen Annahmen meiner Erfahrung nach um fast 3 Stunden abweichen.

Answer (score 0):

*Vormittag* as defined by the *normaler Umgang* in Bayern means the precise time, when it's too late to say *Morgen* but yet too early to say *Mahlzeit*  as a greeting.